# How to map term name via XPath node feed using xpathparser into Term reference field?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I have an xml feed to import to and mapped to a content type. However, there are fields that are referenced to taxonomy. The fields that are not referenced seems to be working fine and are getting picked up. But those that are referenced to a taxonomy vocabulary are not.

How can I import data from xml from say:

```
<properties>
  <item>
    <refid>1234</refid>
    <propertytype>Apartment</propertytype>
    <!-- ... -->
  </item>
</properties>
```

I want to be able to import `propertytype` to this content type as 'Apartment' as referenced to a taxonomy vocabulary - `Property Types`:

```
Property Types (Taxonomy Vocab)
Apartment
Townhouse
Villa
etc...
```

I've learned that taxonomy referenced fields stores data to a separate table in the database. Does this mean I have to manually do insert query to these tables separately? Or is has anyone encountered the same predicament?

Comment: Are you using the Taxonomy Fields module or only the Taxanomy module?

Comment: only taxonomy module..

Answer (score 3):

You create taxonomy vocabulary by name property types and attach this to the content type you are using for feeds import.
Map the fields accordingly.

- `//properties/item` as context
- `propertytype` to the term reference field you have attached to the content-type

But remember just create vocabulary and don't add any terms. Once you do feeds import you can see the terms under property type vocabulary.